# Convert Bytes Into UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When I convert my NSMutableArray Into NSdata,I get NSMutableArray data in bytes.
Now I want To convert it into UIImage, because I want to send My Array data by Email, but I get null in UIImage.

Here is my code.

```
     NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewArray];
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      [controller addAttachmentData:image mimeType:@"image/png"
             fileName:@"labelData"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an image to string you need a method to convert NSData to a base64Encoded string and back (lots of examples http://cocoadev.com/wiki/BaseSixtyFour). The easiest ones to use are categories on NSData so you can do something like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:viewArray];
NSString* pictureDataString = [self base64EncodingWithLineLength:data];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData 
        dataFromBase64EncodedString: pictureDataString]];
[controller addAttachmentData:image mimeType:@"image/png"
         fileName:@"labelData"];


- (NSString *) base64EncodingWithLineLength:(NSData*) data {

const unsigned char* bytesArr=[data bytes];
unsigned int lineLength=0;
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[data length]];
unsigned long ixtext = 0;
unsigned long lentext = [data length];
long ctremaining = 0;
unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
unsigned short i = 0;
unsigned short charsonline = 0, ctcopy = 0;
unsigned long ix = 0;

while( YES ) {
    ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
    if( ctremaining <= 0 ) break;

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        ix = ixtext + i;
        if( ix < lentext ) inbuf[i] = bytesArr[ix];
        else inbuf [i] = 0;
    }

    outbuf [0] = (inbuf [0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
    outbuf [1] = ((inbuf [0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf [1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
    outbuf [2] = ((inbuf [1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf [2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
    outbuf [3] = inbuf [2] & 0x3F;
    ctcopy = 4;

    switch( ctremaining ) {
        case 1:
            ctcopy = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            ctcopy = 3;
            break;
    }

    for( i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++ )
        [result appendFormat:@"%c", encodingTable[outbuf[i]]];

    for( i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++ )
        [result appendString:@"="];

    ixtext += 3;
    charsonline += 4;

    if( lineLength > 0 ) {
        if( charsonline >= lineLength ) {
            charsonline = 0;
            [result appendString:@"\n"];
        }
    }
}

return [NSString stringWithString:result];
}




static char encodingTable[64] = {
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/' };
```

Try this way may help you out.

Comment: I hope now will surely work, use the edited code. Let me know if any issue occurs

Comment: I hope this will work now, as I have edited it not getting any error now. Actually I have replicate same scenario for this everytime in the demo app and thats why sometimes error occurs.

Comment: Thanx dear.i apply your are editing code.i got no error.but there is some worning ..Note List[459:207]+[NSData dataFromBase64EncodedString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26aea74*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',reason: '+[NSData dataFromBase64EncodedString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x26aea74'

Comment: Dear if you free ..just visit my profile.i post this question with detail ,i think if you check this ,you will suggest better solution for me..

Comment: Please Check link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479036/nsmutablearray-data-attachement-with-e-mail-body