# Data Attachement in E-mail?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdata, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I save my objects in NSMutablearray in NSData formate.No i am try to attached in E-mail Body.here is code.

```
  - (IBAction)sendEmail
     {

   if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
  {
       NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"example@yahoo.com"];
       MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController 
            alloc] init];
       controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
       [controller setSubject:@"Iphone Game"];
       NSString *string = [viewArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
       NSString *emailBody = string; 
       NSLog(@"test=%@",emailBody);
       [controller setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
       [controller setToRecipients:recipients];
       [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
       [controller release];
    }
else 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
            message:@"Your device is not set up for email." delegate:self 
            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];   
    [alert release];
}

 }
```

I get no error,but not see any data in E-mail.in NSLog i see this..2012-05-07 15:33:22.984 Note List[273:207] test=>]please suggest any one better solution for me how i attached my NSMutableArray data in E-mail body..

Comment: Can you elaborate on where the mutable data is coming from? How do you create the instance?

Comment: Thanx sir for response me.i post this question with detail in other way just visit my profile ..i think there You understand my problem well,i think sir You suggest better solution for me..Thanx

Comment: Can you post a link to the question? I couldn't find it from your profile.

Comment: Thanx again here is link sir.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479036/nsmutablearray-data-attachement-with-e-mail-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not clear with your question, try this way to set your data. and check the values you are going to set before passing it to composer,

see this

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString *mSubject;

    if(isInvite)
    {
        mSubject=@"TAPP Invitation";
    }
    else 
    {
        mSubject= @"TAPP email";
    }

    [picker setSubject:mSubject];

    NSString *mBody;

    if(isInvite)
    {
        NSString *pTappId=[[DataModel sharedDataModel] getValueForKey:USER_TAPP_ID];
        NSString *currentUserName=[[DataModel sharedDataModel] getValueForKey:CURRENT_USER_NAME];
         mBody=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>Hi,<br><br>We already know one another, and I would like us to keep in touch.<br><br>Let's connect through TAPP (<a href=\"http://download.mytapp.com\">Download Here</a>) a smarter, private way to exchange and manage contact information.<br><br>Join TAPP and secure your preferred, unique ID before it is too late, and then connect with me. My TAPP ID is %@.<br><br>For more information, <a href=\"http://www.mytapp.com\">click here</a><br><br>Regards,<br><br>%@</BODY></HTML>",pTappId,currentUserName];
    }
    else 
    {
        mBody= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY><br /><br />Connected by <a href=http://www.mytapp.com>TAPP</a></BODY></HTML>"];
    }

    // Set up recipients
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:selectedEmailId]; 
    //NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""]; 

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"png"];

    //NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo.image);
    //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"abc.png"];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *emailBody = mBody;
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

    [picker release];
```

Comment: Dear i have no idea , i just want to attached my array data which is NSdata formate in E-mail body..my array contain uilabel along with all the properties.dear you know well UIlabel properties.for exp..textcolor.background color.text etc..no i try to send all these data of array in email.please suggest better solution for me .thanx.

Comment: - (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData *)attachment mimeType:(NSString *)mimeType fileName:(NSString *)filename

Comment: see this method if it helps you

Comment: if you have ns data formate then why this method is not working for you

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to attach the data as a standard email attachment, use this:

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(artworkImageView.image, 0.0);
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Photo.jpeg"];
```

The `data` can be whatever you want, just give an appropriate mime type and file name.

Comment: If the data is just text, just set it directly with the mime type set to `text/plain` and a filename with a `.txt` extension.

Comment: No sir my data is not only text..but it contain all the UILabel properties.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to attach the data bytes from view properties ... this isn't the best approach, but you have use `application/octet-stream` as a mime type and it should be unarchivable with `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, though [using plists](http://ipgames.wordpress.com/tutorials/writeread-data-to-plist-file/) would be easier.

Comment: @ Ash Furrow Thanx sir .its means through this method it is impossible for me to send my array data in E-mail.if sir You see some possiblitiy through this method then please guide me.beacuse if i using plists that you suggest ,then my flow of application is change.Thanx

Comment: @ Ash Furrow , i have costum objects and i think its not store in plist.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your definition of the viewArray is wrong?

In your .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewArray;
```

In your .m file:

```
@synthesize viewArray;
```

Please have a look at the apple docs for the method "componentsJoindedByString", because I can't found a error quite know.

My test with a viewArray initialization from the api: (works good)

```
- (IBAction)sendEmail {

  self.viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"here", @"be", @"dragons", nil];

  if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
  {
    NSArray *recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"example@yahoo.com"];
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController 
                                            alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject:@"Iphone Game"];

    //is anything in the array?
    NSLog(@"viewArray: %@", viewArray);

    NSString *string = [viewArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    NSString *emailBody = string; 
    NSLog(@"test=%@",emailBody);
    [controller setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
    [controller setToRecipients:recipients];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
  }
  else 
  { 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                                message:@"Your device is not set up for     email." delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];   
    [alert release];
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thanx for response me ,sir i apply your method.i get the objects store in viewArray .in console i see this..2012-05-07 18:48:00.065 Note List[279:207] test=<UILabel: 0x8250850; frame = (140 341; 56 19); text = 'Xxxxxxx'; clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x824e6d0>> but no data show in E-mail.